# Динамическое создание Calendar на VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

Динамически создаю на этапе Page_Load в таблице на страницы обычные контролы: тексбокс, комбобокс, чекбокс - все нормально создается, отображается, обработчики обрабатываются. Пытаюсь создать календарь - ошибок не выдает, но и контрол не появляется в DOM'е.

```
Dim newDtEl As New Calendar
newDtEl.ID = spElement.getAttribute("id")
newDtEl.AutoPostBack = True
spCell.Controls.Add(newDtEl)
```

Где я не прав? В чем может быть загвоздка? Как сделать, чтобы он отобразился?
Таблица объявлена в aspx:

```
<table width="50%" align="center" id="ElTable" runat="server">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Date</td>
            <td><asp:calendar ID="dasd" runat="server"></asp:calendar></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>UserDate</td>
            <td><uc1:UserControlWithCalendar ID="Calendar1" runat="server"></uc1:UserControlWithCalendar></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Вот так эти контролы отображаются. Строку и ячейку добавляю динамически так:

```
Dim spRow As New HtmlTableRow, spCell As New HtmlTableCell
spRow.Cells.Add(spCell)
ElTable.Rows.Add(spRow)
```

.NET Framework 2.0, VS2005

Comment: У вас в примере TextBox, по клику на нему должен появляться календарь?

Comment: ошибка, неправильно указал. просто, сейчас пока сделал текстбокс с валидацией даты, но это не совсем то, что нужно.

Comment: Можете добавить в вопрос код создания spCell и код создания таблицы, в которой они находятся?

Comment: Строка и ячейка в таблицу у вас корректно добавляются, т.е. что-то типа `spRow.Cells.Add(spCell)` и `ElTable.Rows.Add(spRow)`?

Comment: да, именно так.

Answer (score 1):

Вот такой минимальный пример + ваша разметка отрабатывают нормально, календарь создается:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    Dim spRow As New HtmlTableRow, spCell As New HtmlTableCell
    Dim newDtEl As New Calendar

    newDtEl.ID = "calTest" ' у календаря нет свойства AutoPostBack '

    spCell.Controls.Add(newDtEl)
    spRow.Cells.Add(New HtmlTableCell With {.InnerText = "test"})
    spRow.Cells.Add(spCell)
    ElTable.Rows.Add(spRow)

End Sub
```

Comment: в идеале так и надо - это то, с чего я начал, но не работает. версия .NET Framework 2.0, VS2005 - может быть критично?

Comment: По идее не должно влиять. Может быть, вы где-то ставите `Visible = false` для таблицы или другого родительского контрола? Тогда контрол и все вложенные в него контролы не будут создаваться.

Comment: Нет, visible вообще не трогаю. Только у ячейки меняю ширину при инициализации. Никаких других действий с таблицей пока не совершаю. Сама таблица отображается нормально, остальные контролы, которые также добавляю, тоже. Беда только с календарем. Ну и с usercontrol, но, думаю, проблема общая.